# Generate many plots at once in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a function which generates a plot:
`function(x, y,"name")`

I would like to generate as many plots as "names" present in character **z**

**z**

```
[1] "Bzw1"          "Dnajc1"        "Ppig"          "Prex1"         "Dpm1"          "Prpf38b"      
[7] "Snrnp70"       "Spty2d1"       "Cbl"           "Anxa2"         "Ggnbp2"        "Cltc"
```

and save all of them in a working directory.

Comment: try this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687061/save-multiple-plots-in-loop-in-r

Comment: Have you tried with `lapply`?

Comment: purrr::map thing to try.

Comment: @RyanJohn doesn't work, it takes only the first name and generates many identical plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your function is `custom_plot`. Then, try with this:

```
lapply(X = z,
       FUN = function(name)
       {
           png(filename = paste0(name, ".png"))
           custom_plot(x, y, name)
           dev.off()
       })
```

Answer (score 1):

Voted for above answer. However this is one particular place where a 
for loop is not a bad choice either. As in:

```
z <- c("Bronx","Staten","Tribeca")
func <- function(i,z){

  filename <- paste0("plot_",i,".png")
  png(filename)
  plot(1:30,rep(which(i==z),30)) # just getting 3 simple plots to print
  dev.off()}

for (i in z) func(i,z)
# You will find the plots as .png files in your working directory 
# with "plot_" prepended to each name
```

Comment: Why a list? No good coding reason to, I agree. Mentally, however, I tend to visualize lists as ordered sets (my early coding experience waayyy back was in LISP and Prolog though I did use APL a lot as well--not that I really speak any of those 3 any more--and vectors as wholes. Since this is a list processing question, I went with that way.

Comment: As for the rest, I felt it was needed to provide an example the asker could actually see the results of. Hope that was correct thinking.

Comment: Certainly fair enough re: the working example. I'll gladly upvote if you switch `list` to `c`.

Comment: Weelllll...I guess so!